# Migration to Azure Service Fabric - Architectural considerations

Tags: azure, architecture, azure-service-fabric

We are on Azure since 2010 and had a great benefit from a performance and reliability in our application. Azure offers a lot of enterprise-level services and I think that the new "Azure Service Fabric" is great.

What I cannot understand by reading the documentation is the approach on migrating an "old" Cloud Service to the new Service Fabric. Why do we want to migrate? For horizontal scaling and more reliability.

Currently we have a single-instance cloud service, that spins up a lot of subservices. Those subservices are great candidates for microservices. The only problem is that some of these subservices are "runners", i.e. they just cycle on our users database and decide whether an operation (service) has to be run for a particular user or not. 
How would you migrate a service like this considering that more than one instance may run this service?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing to keep in mind is that once a service is started it keeps running, and his lifecycle and uptime is controlled by Service Fabric (ex: it will restart it automatically if it crashes). Second thing to keep in mind is that you will end-up with multiple instances of the service running at the same time (on different nodes), so they will end-up doing the exact same thing on different nodes of your cluster.

Your first reflex could be to have one stateless service kind/instance per runner "subservice" that keeps running and leverage the RunAsync (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-reliable-services-advanced-usage). Personally, I wouldn't take that approach, since this could then require some kind of synchronization between services to prevent useless concurrency, since they do the exact same thing independently.

A better approach would be to have your runner services need to run only once in a while when requested by the "main" service acting as an orchestrator, you could have a Queue based approach where the "main" service submit tasks (messages) to be processed by the runners, who are listening concurrently on the same Queue, making sure that maximum one service instance would complete the task.

For the Queue, think Service Bus or Reliable Concurrent Queue (https://learn.microsoft.com/enus/dotnet/api/microsoft.servicefabric.data.collections.preview.ireliableconcurrentqueue-1).

Comment: Hello Simon, thanks for your reply. You are thinking exactly to what I'm thinking regarding the queue-based subservices. But the problem remains: what the "main" service should be? I cannot model as a Service Fabric service, because it would be multiplied on different instances with the result of putting same messages on the queue. How would you solve this?

Comment: It depends, what is the trigger for the "main" service behavior? Is it time based or event based? Note that you would have the same concerns with horizontal scaling of your existing Cloud Service,

Comment: Yes, I know! That's why I'm trying to understand how much effort should we spend to migrate to Cloud Service. The main service is, normally, time based, for each user. For example, each user must communicate to a webservice each X minutes (where X is a user-based variable). The communication with the webserivce is encapsulated in a "subservice" that listens on a queue. I don't know how to model this "main" service that spit out the message every X minutes.

Comment: I would try something with Actors:
1) Create a Stateless service to serve the HTTP requests coming in to your web service. 
2) Each time the web service is called, update an Actor representing your User and maintain a timer or reminder for that User which would be restarted whenever a new Web Service call is done. 
Links:
3) Upon timer expiration, queue a message to be processed by your runner services.

Comment: Links:
Actors Overview: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-reliable-actors-introduction
Actor Timers and Reminders: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-reliable-actors-timers-reminders

Comment: I think I wasn't clear. The user doesn't call directly a webservice throught HTTP. We have to call a webservice on his behalf every X seconds. It's like this:
foreach(user) { if(now - user.lasttime > X) user.callservice(); }

Comment: Actor suggestion would still be applicable. Create one actor per User, create Timer for each User to queue a message when timer expires (message with sufficient information to know what is the action to execute), have the runner call the webservice on behalf of the user each time the timer expiration message is received.

Comment: Is this still applicable even with hundred thousand users? Thanks

Comment: Microsoft recommends to use Actors when "Your problem space involves a large number (thousands or more) of small, independent, and isolated units of state and logic.". Now, you would need to do a small proof of concept and test what kind of cluster hardware would be required to support your specific scenario (actors using timers), which will vary depending on timer frequency, logic involved and total amount of users triggering at the same time.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you.

Comment: Hello Simon I'm back with this question. I think I found a pattern. My runner service may be just a normal stateless service with just one instance count. In this way I don't have neither bother with synchronization between nodes, nor spin a new reliable actor for each customer. This just works as if the node dies, service Fabric would spin a new instance in a new node. What do you think?